# Old LOCKFILE warning on github repo - I cant clone

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, github, deprecated, lockfile

I have been tasked to work on a website. The site was built in React and calls on most of the content from WordPress. I got the credentials to the host, WordPress, and the github repo. I tried to clone the code. The files came through but when I tried to run npm install, it crashed and I had a lot of OLD LOCKFILE warnings. I have been through the wringer on this and could really use some help. It is a pretty large site and was not put together well. I think my first approach was to update all of the dependencies. I did that but so much of the code was reliant upon the old dependencies that the site just does not render. I then tried reverting to earlier versions of Node and React, npm, all sorts of things. My question is how do I get this to where I can work on this site without the danger of breaking the whole thing. Please help.

As i said, I tried updating all of the dependencies. I have a big problem with react-router being that all of the code relies on  and not . I am also getting a constant error telling me that  cannot be a child of , that I need to use Route or fragment. I went through the code and have made sure that it is compliant but it still gives me the error. I also tried reverting to older Node, React, npm, and openssl versions but it just leads to more problems. I keep going down rabbit holes and killing errors one at a time but always end up with a site that isnt rendering. Just a blank white screen.

```
 {
  "name": "project-mess",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.10",
    "interweave": "^12.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-protect": "^1.0.8",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-ga4": "^1.0.6",
    "react-geocode": "^0.2.3",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7"
  }
}
```